# How do I use Powershell on my computer to use another computer to copy files from a third computer to a fourth computer?

Tags: powershell

Working remotely works fine -- mostly.  Occasionally, I need to copy large files, or large numbers of files, from one server to another or from a vendor's web site to a server (like install sets).  With limited upload speeds through the ISP I use at home, anything that involves large uploads will take a very long time.

It seems PowerShell's ability to run commands remotely should be able to help with this.  I'm trying to create a simple app that will enable me to use another computer to copy from anywhere to anywhere (assuming I have appropriate permissions in all 3 places).

I like `Start-BitsTransfer` because it seems to be much faster and because I can use it to download software from a vendor's web site.

I have created a very simple example that I haven't been able to get to work.

If I log onto "server1" using Remote Desktop and do...

```
$src = "\\server2\c$\myfolder\*"
$dest = "c:\myfolder\"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $src -Destination $dest
```

...it works fine.  All of the files from c:\myfolder on server2 are copied to c:\myfolder on server1.

Trying to remove Remote Desktop from the equation, here's what I have so far:

```
#RemoteCopy.ps1
param(
    [string]$computer,
    [string]$source,
    [string]$destination
)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    $src = $args[0]
    $dest = $args[1]
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $src -Destination $dest
    #Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $dest
} -ArgumentList $source,$destination
```

From my workstation:

```
.\RemoteCopy.ps1 -computer server1 -source "\\server2\c$\myfolder\*" -destination "c:\myfolder\"
```

But nothing happens.

Since I'm logged onto the network on my workstation, there shouldn't be a credential problem.  If there was, I would expect to receive an error message.

For this specific example, my workstation, server1, and server2 are on the same domain and my user account is an admin on all three machines.
I'm currently using PowerShell 5.1.

**Responding to comments**

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    $src = $args[0]
    $dest = $args[1]
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $src -Destination $dest
    #Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $dest
} -ArgumentList $source,$destination -Credential $Credential
```

...behaves the same.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    $src = $args[0]
    $dest = $args[1]
    $cred = $args[2]
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $src -Destination $dest -Credential $cred
    #Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $dest
} -ArgumentList $source,$destination,$Credential -Credential $Credential
```

...produces an error:

```
The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified service does not
exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704DD)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBits
   TransferCommand
    + PSComputerName        : server1
```

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    $src = $args[0]
    $dest = $args[1]
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $src -Destination $dest -Credential domain\username
    #Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $dest
} -ArgumentList $source,$destination -Credential domain\username
```

...produces the same error

And if I try to follow https://www.ipswitch.com/blog/the-infamous-double-hop-problem-in-powershell (the first link on https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+doublehop%27&t=h_&ia=web) ...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name RemoteCopy -RunAsCredential 'domain\username' -Force
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    $src = $args[0]
    $dest = $args[1]
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $src -Destination $dest -Credential domain\username
} -ArgumentList $source,$destination -ConfigurationName RemoteCopy.
```

...I get different errors:

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (server1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : server1

[server1] Connecting to remote server server1 failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service
cannot process the request. Cannot find the RemoteCopy. session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the server1 computer.
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (server1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidResourceUri,PSSessionStateBroken
```

And if I remove the `.` from the end of the ConfigurationName argument in the Invoke-Command call, I get the same error I saw at the start of this rework:

```
The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified service does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704DD)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBits
   TransferCommand
    + PSComputerName        : server1
```

I also read https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/847119/Resolve-Double-Hop-Issue-in-PowerShell-Remoting.  But other reading indicates the CredSSP is not secure.  Credentials can be stolen.  So I'd need to run this one by my security and infrastructure experts.

If this is a problem with credentials (that for some reason doesn't generate any error messages), how would I get through that?

Comment: You may very well have a credential problem; I don't remember the details, but there are conditions under which credentials do not transfer, and must be re-supplied.

Comment: As per 'Jeff Zeitln', this is called a potential [double-hop auth restriction/issues](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+doublehop%27&t=h_&ia=web) and you have to plan to work with or around it.